# jquery ui widget displaying as a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-ui-widget

I'm trying to make a range widget like this http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range. I've copied the source code and it results in a text-input instead of a slider. This is the code I'm working with. Also I moved the style attribute to a linked css file. Doing so the output changed from nothing to the text input.

This is my head:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="../jscript/questions.js"></script>
  <script>
     jQuery.noConflict()
  $(function() {
    $('#slider-range').slider({
      range: true,
      min: 25,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
  </script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/questions.css">
</head>
```

This is the html of the widget:

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount"  >
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#slider-range{
  border:0;
  color:#f6931f; 
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in the console? Some of the relative urls may be your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from declaring `jQuery.noConflict()`

By doing so you are no longer able to directly access `jQuery` using `$`

If you need `noConflict` you can fix your code by changing:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
$(function() {
```

To

```
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(function($) {/* "$" argument allows using "$" inside the ready handler*/
```

[**Working demo of your code**](http://plnkr.co/edit/I5lY29beLhViHXgibHZD?p=preview)

Learn how to use browser console to check for errors. You should be seeing errors for `"$" is not defined` or similar depending on browser

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

relinquishes the $ variable so when you call it after its not assigned.

Doc
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MfegM/